# Firebase cloud functions not working properly with cloud messaging

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am having problems with the Firebase cloud functions and cloud messaging. I can see in the logs that the function is run when needed, but no cloud message is sent.(nothing happens) I am trying to send users a notification when the function is triggered but for some reason, nothing happens and no errors are thrown.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.notifySeniorOnTicketAcceptance = functions.firestore
.document("tickets/{ticketId}")
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const newData = change.after.data();
  const previousData = change.before.data();

  // Check if the isAccepted field changed from false to true
  if (newData.isAccepted === true && previousData.isAccepted !== true) {
    const seniorUserId = context.params.ticketId;


    return admin.firestore().collection("seniors").doc(seniorUserId).get()
        .then((seniorSnapshot) => {
          if (seniorSnapshot.exists) {
            const seniorData = seniorSnapshot.data();
            if (seniorData && seniorData.deviceToken) {
              // Send notification to the senior
              const message = {
                data: {
                  title: "Ticket Accepted",
                  body: "Your ticket has been accepted.",
                },
                token: seniorData.deviceToken,
              };

              return admin.messaging().send(message);
            } else {
              console.error("Seniordocument is missing deviceToken field.");
              return null;
            }
          } else {
            console.error("Senior document not found.");
            return null;
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error retrieving senior information:", error);
          return null;
        });
  }

  return null;
});
```

Comment: "nothing happens" is really hard to help with, but it's also unlikely to be true. Did you already debug the code and see which lines execute? If so: does it ever reach the `admin.messaging().send(message)` line? If so: what is the response you get from that API call?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen How do you debug a cloud function? Because I don't see it in the logs.

Comment: "I can see in the logs that the function is run when needed", so it sounds like the function is running. Add more logging yourself to see what happens in the code (log all values, check if they match your expectation): https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs?gen=2nd

Answer (score 0):

i did some changes ,there could be other reason but try the below and let us know

```
exports.notifySeniorOnTicketAcceptance = functions.firestore
  .document("tickets/{ticketId}")
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const newData = change.after.data();
    const previousData = change.before.data();

    // Check if the isAccepted field changed from false to true
    if (newData.isAccepted === true && previousData.isAccepted !== true) {
      const seniorUserId = newData.seniorUserId; //<---try by pass the new data not the context.params.ticketId; 
                          //i don't know about you flow but it is what i was thinking so for ?

      return await admin  //<-use await
        .firestore()
        .collection("seniors")
        .doc(seniorUserId)
        .get()
        .then(async (seniorSnapshot) => {
          if (seniorSnapshot.exists) {
            const seniorData = seniorSnapshot.data();
            if (seniorData && seniorData.deviceToken) {
              // Send notification to the senior
              const message = {
                data: {
                  title: "Ticket Accepted",
                  body: "Your ticket has been accepted.",
                },
                token: seniorData.deviceToken,
              };

              return await admin.messaging().send(message); //<-use await
            } else {
              console.error("Senior document is missing deviceToken field.");
              return null;
            }
          } else {
            console.error("Senior document not found.");
            return null;
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error retrieving senior information:", error);
          return null;
        });
    }

    return null;
  });
```